# Gdb task suspended (tty output)

Tags: background, gdb, debian, tty

When attempting to run a binary (in the background) in gdb after hitting a breakpoint I get the following message :

[1]  + 4636 suspended (tty output)  gdb exploit_me

The problem seems to happen whatever i'm running gdb in bash, zsh or as root it appears that it happens only when i had set a breakpoint.

➜  Buffer_Overlow_1 gdb --version

```
GNU gdb (Debian 8.3-1) 8.3
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

➜  Buffer_Overlow_1 stty -a

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl -ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke -flusho -extpro
```

c

Here is the program "exploit_me"

➜  Buffer_Overlow_1 cat exploit_me.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void func(char *arg)
{
    char buffer[64];
    strcpy(buffer,arg);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2) printf("binary \n");
    else func(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your forgot to ask a question. You also didn't show your complete session (how you are actually interacting with GDB, how you are setting a breakpoint, etc.).

Presumably, your question is "why does this happen and what can I do to prevent it from happening".

The `suspended (tty output)` means that the background task attempted to read input from the terminal, and was stopped with `SIGTTYOUT`. Read more about it [here](http://curiousthing.org/sigttin-sigttou-deep-dive-linux).

If this was allowed, your foreground shell and background task would race to read whatever you are typing, with each getting ~50% of the typed characters. This is almost never what you want.

As to what can you do to prevent this: don't run GDB in the background, unless you are running it with `--bath` flag and supplying all the commands it needs via a script.